# Making cucumber test succeed if there is no test data

Tags: javascript, cucumber, capybara

I am writing cucumber tests for a web-app that we are making for a 3rd party where they have complete control of our shared test-environment. As things are right now, my tests fail on almost a daily basis due to data being removed or changed in our test environment, giving me a lot of grief.

What I would like to do is to skip a scenario given that the test-data needed to execute it isn't there. That is, I would like to be able to skip a scenario based on me finding a specific element on a page or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...although its not marked as successful

```
Feature: dummy

Scenario: First
  Given I set sessions to "10"
  Then it should have "10"

Scenario: second
  Given it should have "10"
  Then I set sessions to "10"
```

steps

```
Given(/^I set sessions to "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  @data = ""
end

Then(/^it should have "(.*?)"$/) do |arg1|
  @data = "test"
end

AfterStep do |scenario|
  scenario.skip_invoke! if @data.empty?  
end

2 scenarios (1 skipped, 1 passed)
4 steps (1 skipped, 3 passed)
0m0.008s
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but I am just wondering exactly what "scenario.skip_invoke!" does as I am unable to find any documentation on it. If it marks the "failed" scenario as skipped without affecting any subsequent scenarios then this should work.

Comment: I've tested it now and it works, but unfortunately, the test goes "green" in the HTML-formatter. Does anyone know if there is a way to make tests that are skipped in this way go yellow just like unimplemented tests

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip the scenario and make it to look like yellow in HTML reports, you can try calling pending step in your step definitions like this:

```
steps %{
Given pending
}
```